# Sqlite Jdbc driver is extremly slow

Tags: java, performance, sqlite, select, jdbc

I am selecting all columns from table with 17 columns without any joins.

The result return 39761 rows.

In "DB Broswer for sqlite" it took 689ms 
In JDCB driver it took **252s** to execute and loop over ResultSet , in which I create objects according to selected data (no condition,no loops just simple new object creation with data from ResultSet)

Why is this significat difference? My table has primary key ,so it has index on it.
How to speed it up? I am using latest version of jsqlite-jdbc driver, but I also tried version 3.7.1 and it was same slow...

Comment: An index is not used when you are scanning the entire table. How fast is it without those objects?

Comment: I removed part of create objects and no change , but I also found out , that resultSet.next() is taking too much time